# Downloading OpenOffice PDF via PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I have an Issue:
Downloading PDF created with OpenOffice are always "blank".
Here is the code:

```
$filename = "test.pdf";
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"test.pdf\"");
$file = file($filename);
foreach($file AS $fileshow)
{
    print $fileshow;
}
exit();
```

PDFs fron other sources work like a charm.
What am I dowing wrong?

Comment: Is it blank when you open it via OpenOffice? via other PDF viewer?

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Comment: after some trying: in "PDF-XChange Viewer" it is blank, other Viewer have no problem.. just strange...